Verify the inequality: $\frac{k!}{(k-N)!}\, (1-p)^{k-N} - e^{-kp} \, k^N>0$
Let $k>1$ be an integer and $0<p<1$ such that $kp\geq 1$.
I want to show the following inequality:
$$\binom{k}{\lfloor (k+1)p \rfloor}\,p^{\lfloor (k+1)p \rfloor} (1-p)^{k-\lfloor (k+1)p \rfloor} > e^{-kp} \dfrac{(kp)^{\lfloor kp \rfloor}}{\lfloor kp \rfloor!}.$$

My approach (later changed the wording a bit for clarity in my argument):
Let $N\geq 1$ be an integer. For any integer $k \geq N+1$, choose $p \in [\frac{N}{k}, \frac{N+1}{k})$ so that $\lfloor kp \rfloor = N$.
There are two cases: $\lfloor (k+1)p \rfloor=N$ for $\frac{N}{k}\leq p < \frac{N+1}{k+1}$ and  $\lfloor (k+1)p \rfloor = N+1$ for $\frac{N+1}{k+1}\leq p < \frac{N+1}{k}$. Let us first treat the case $\lfloor (k+1)p \rfloor=N$. For this case, after simplifying the above inequality, we get
$$ \dfrac{k!}{(k-N)!}\, (1-p)^{k-N} - e^{-kp} \, k^N>0$$
The idea is to use the induction on $N$. In particular, I wish to show that for any integers $N\geq 1$ and $k\geq 2$
$$ \dfrac{k!}{(k-N)!}\, (1-p)^{k-N} - e^{-kp} \, k^N>0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{when $\frac{N}{k}\leq p < \frac{N+1}{k+1}$}$$
Proceed by induction. When $N=1$, the above the inequality gets reduced to
$$(1-p)^{k-1} - e^{-kp}>0.$$
After moving $e^{-kp}$ to the right and taking the natural logarithms, the above is equivalent to
$$f_k(p) := (k-1)\,\ln{(1-p)} +kp >0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{for $\frac{2}{k+1} > p \geq \frac{1}{k}$}$$
Differentiating $f_k$ w.r.t $p$ gives $f_k^\prime (p) = \frac{1-kp}{1-p}$, which is non-positive on $[\frac{1}{k}, \frac{2}{k+1})$. Therefore, $f_k(p) \geq f_k(\frac{2}{k+1}) = \frac{2k}{1+k} + (k-1) \ln{\left(\frac{k-1}{k+1}\right)}>0$ for $k\geq 2$. We will now assume the inequality holds for $N=i <k$.
Consider the case $N=i+1\leq k$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{k!}{(k-i-1)!}\, (1-p)^{k-i-1} - e^{-kp} \, k^{i+1} & = \prod_{n=0}^N (k-i+n)\, (1-p)^{k-i-1} - e^{-kp} \, k^{i+1} \\
& = \dfrac{k-i}{1-p}\,\prod_{n=1}^N (k-i+n)\, (1-p)^{k-i} - e^{-kp} \, k^{i+1}\\
&> \dfrac{k-i}{1-p}\,e^{-kp} \, k^i - e^{-kp} \, k^{i+1}\\
& = e^{-kp} \, k^i \left(\dfrac{k-i}{1-p} - k\right)\\
& = e^{-kp} \, k^i\, \dfrac{kp -i}{1-p}>0
\end{align*}
Here, the first inequality is due to the induction hypothesis and the second inequality is due to the fact that $kp\geq N=i+1$.
Finally, the case $\lfloor (k+1)p \rfloor = N+1$ follows from $\lfloor (k+1)p \rfloor = N$ since
$$\mathbb{P}(X= N+1)\geq \mathbb{P}(X= N),$$ where $X \sim \text{Bin}(k,p)$ as the maximum of the distribution occurs when $X = \lfloor (k+1)p \rfloor$.

Question: Is my argument correct, particularly the set up for the induction? Your feedback would be appreciated.

Is the result basically saying that the Poisson distribution is more "left leaning" than the Binomial distributions approximating it, in particular past the "middle" $m:=\lfloor (k+1)p\rfloor$, the p.d.f. of the Binomial is always "fatter" than the p.d.f. of the Poisson? I wonder if there is a probabilistic proof.

@D.R.  The inequality says the maximum of a binomial r.v X
is greater than the maximum of Poisson (with the parameter $\mathbb{E}[X]$
). Anyway, yes, I think there could be a probabilistic proof (a better and nicer) of this fact.

doesn't seem to be quite the maximum; here $\lambda=kp$, and Wikipedia says the mode of Poisson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution is at $\lfloor \lambda \rfloor$ and $\lceil \lambda \rceil -1$.

@D.R. Yes, you're correct. The exponent and the factorial term on the right hand side of the inequality should be $\lfloor kp \rfloor$ there (I was careless). I messed up the notation a little bit. I needed to mention that for any $k\geq 2$, there exists an integer $N\geq 1$ such that $N+1 > kp \geq N$.

Also there are some nice images that support your result here (showing that Poisson has fatter tails on both ends --- so my first comment was wrong --- and is shorter in the middle than the Binomial) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3775860/405572
